# IPython Search PYTHONPATH for file

Tags: python, path, ipython, pythonpath

Is there any way to make it so that IPython searches through your system path to find a file if only the name of the file is given?

I have a file `foo_060112.dat` that lives in a folder containing a lot of data files that are uniquely named in a folder in my path. I want to be able to simply call a `load` or `open` function on this file without specifying the full path---is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own function to search through the path and return an open file object according to the mode you select:

```
import sys
import os

def my_open(filename, mode):
    for path in sys.path:
        try:
            return open(os.path.join(path, filename), mode)
        except IOError:
            continue
    return None
```

Example: `my_open('foo_060112.dat', 'rb')`

Answer (score -2):

I thinks this may help you:

```
import os,sys

path = os.sytem('locate foo_060112.dat')

print path
```

or you can  also use :

```
_SOURCE_FILE_PATH = '/home/admin/'
_each_folder = os.walk("%s/" %(_SOURCE_FILE_PATH))  
for x in _each_folder:           
        print x   
        if x[1] == []:   
            for y in x[2]:
                 if y == 'locate foo_060112.dat'    
                      f = open(y,'r')
                      data = f.read()
```

Comment: `os.system` doesn't return the stdout/stderr streams from programs.  Anyway, that's not what this question is about.